# View only latest added items if item already exists (same name)

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, list-view, calculated-column

Need some help figuring out how to go about this!

I have a list, people will add items to it, sometimes with the same title (which is correct).

We then group these items by the column 'title' on the list.

We want people to create new items, rather than editing the old one, so we have a log of the new additions.

For example:
The list would have 4 items, 3 with the title 'dog' and 1 with the title 'cat'

We would then group the items with the title dog, and group with the title cat.

However, I also want to have a view where we only see the last added item for each title - so we would only see the latest 'dog' item, and the latest 'cat' item.

I couldn't filter by time/date, because some groups may not have had items added to in a while.

Is there a solution to this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To View only latest added items if item already exists (same name), you can modify view, Group by Title:

[image]

Then sort by ID in descending order:

[image]

Then in item limit section, set Number of items to display to 1, and choose "Limit the total number of items returned to the specified amount", click ok to save the view:

[image]

Comment: This is perfect thank you! Much appreciated!

Comment: for some reason I see only one item and from one group. All other groups just not shown

Comment: I use expanded in the Group By

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit confusing if we see it from logic side, but did you try using the versioning feature !

check this : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-and-configure-versioning-for-a-list-or-library-1555d642-23ee-446a-990a-bcab618c7a37